# Division of sucessive columns by one another in a dataframe, subject to a condition

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I am an using Python occasionnally and not very good at it. I am stuck with the following issue which I am sure is easy to solve... Let's  assume we have the following 'df_initial' dataframe as an input.

```
print (df)
     Product       type    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0   BURGUNDY     actual  645  600  720  640  500  320  300
1   BORDEAUX     actual  730  730  710  500  500  450  450
2  CHAMPAGNE     actual  320  260  280  100  100  100    0
3   BURGUNDY  objective  800  760  720  640  600  560  520
4   BORDEAUX  objective  750  730  710  690  670  550  630
5  CHAMPAGNE  objective  500  490  480    0    0    0    0
```

I create the following pivot table :

```
df_pivot = df_initial.pivot_table(index='Product', columns=['type'],
                                  aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image]

I would like to calculate a ratio actual/objective for each product at each location 1, 2, 3, ..., 6 with the additional condition that the ratio should be set to 100% if the division is impossible (for any row where the value in the 'objective' column is equal to zero).

```
ratio_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_pivot.index)
```

I define the following function :

```
def division(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a/b
```

Then I try to apply the function :

```
for col in df_pivot.columns:
    if col[1] == 'objective':
        continue
    ratio_df[col[0]] = division (df_pivot[(col[0], 'actual')] , df_pivot[(col[0], 'objective')])
```

This returns :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I understand why this cannot work but I do not know how to write the script correctly.

I expect a table like this :

[image]

I tried to change the function into :

```
def division(a, b):
    if b.values[0] == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a / b.values[0]
```

and then t:

```
ratio_df[col[0]] = df_pivot[col].apply(division, b=df_pivot.loc[:, (col[0], 'objective')])
```

but this does not produce the correct output.

Comment: Images of code/data are not accepted. Please [edit] your question with the data as text to form a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html), then slice with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the `Inf` by 1 and optionally format with [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
tmp = df_initial.groupby(['type', 'Product']).sum()

ratio_df = (tmp.loc['actual']
            .div(tmp.loc['objective'])
            .replace(np.inf, 1).fillna(1)
            .applymap('{:.0%}'.format) # optional (to format as %)
            )
```

Or with your initial `pivot_table` with [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) for easier slicing:

```
df_pivot = (df_initial
            .pivot_table(index='Product', columns='type', aggfunc='sum')
            .swaplevel(axis=1)
           )

out = (df_pivot['actual']
       .div(df_pivot['objective'])
       .replace(np.inf, 1).fillna(1)
       .applymap('{:.0%}'.format)
      )
```

*NB. for recent pandas versions, replace [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) by [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html).*

Output:

```
             0     1     2     3     4     5     6
Product                                          
BORDEAUX   97%  100%  100%   72%   75%   82%   71%
BURGUNDY   81%   79%  100%  100%   83%   57%   58%
CHAMPAGNE  64%   53%   58%  100%  100%  100%  100%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with division by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and selecting `MultiIndex` levels by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) , last use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for replacement `INF`, multiple by `100` and replace missing values by `1`:

```
df1 = df_initial.groupby(['type', 'Product']).sum()

out = df1.xs('actual').div(df1.xs('objective')).replace(np.inf, 1).mul(100).fillna(1)
print (out)
                   0           1           2           3           4  \
Product                                                                
BORDEAUX   97.333333  100.000000  100.000000   72.463768   74.626866   
BURGUNDY   80.625000   78.947368  100.000000  100.000000   83.333333   
CHAMPAGNE  64.000000   53.061224   58.333333  100.000000  100.000000   

                    5          6  
Product                           
BORDEAUX    81.818182  71.428571  
BURGUNDY    57.142857  57.692308  
CHAMPAGNE  100.000000 100.000000
```

For percentage add [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and remove multiple by `100`:

```
out = (df1.xs('actual')
          .div(df1.xs('objective'))
          .replace(np.inf, 1)
          .fillna(1)
          .applymap('{:.0%}'.format))
print (out)
             0     1     2     3     4     5     6
Product                                           
BORDEAUX   97%  100%  100%   72%   75%   82%   71%
BURGUNDY   81%   79%  100%  100%   83%   57%   58%
CHAMPAGNE  64%   53%   58%  100%  100%  100%  100%
```